# mapping byte arrary to virtual file in java

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, ipc

I am developing an Android application while using a JNI library. The library opens a file and does some actions. I am thinking of a mechanism to write some data to a file in my Java code and passing that file path to the native code. The point is that those contents are confidential and instead of writing data to actual file, I need something like fork mechanism to have something like a virtual file. So then just my own application has access to the contents.

Is there any mechanism available or I should try to change the whole library?

Comment: What about sharing Input/Output streams?

Comment: Is it possible to write 1MB of data to stdout and read it from native library? If so, what is file path of stdin? Actually, that native library is so big that I can not change its general behavior of getting file path and reading file contents.

Comment: You probably can change it, with a recursive search and replace.  But you may be able to accomplish what you want by creating a named pipe with mkfifo() or even simply by using an actual file in the private storage.

Comment: Sounds like you need to rewrite your JNI. I don't know what the fork mechanism has to do with virtual files.

Comment: It seems so, since even a named pipe or a private file can be accessed if the device is rooted.